# Round all decimals in a column and count them?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, rounding, countif

I am trying to accomplish three things in Excel:

1. Round all decimals in a column by 3 decimal places.
2. Count all positive integers, count all negative integers and lastly count all zeros.
3. Then I would like to find the sum of all collected data i.e.

**Count:** 797 **Sum:** 22,081

**Count:** 297 **Sum:** -22,580

**Count:** 1,102 **Sum:** 0

Can anyone help me, or at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in ColumnA and no column label, you don't mind a helper column and by "Round all decimals in a column by 3 decimal places" you mean "to 3 D.P." then in B1 and copied down to suit:

```
 =ROUND(A1,3)
```

Other formulae (I hope obvious which is which):

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,">"&0)  
=SUMIF(B:B,">"&0)  
=COUNTIF(B:B,"<"&0)  
=SUMIF(B:B,"<"&0)  
=COUNTIF(B:B,0)  
=SUMIF(B:B,0)
```

though the last is `0` by definition.